# How do i figure out my scale, so i can place new vertice?

Tags: scale

So I imported a zoom level 16 Google maps terrain from a SketchUp.dae.

I then scaled it to 0.00254 x,y and z.

Now I need to draw roads on said terrain which are accurately placed.

I have the several vertices that I want to draw but i dont know how to figure out their scale so I can draw them.

Basically, I have a terrain map that at 0,0 is located at -9.13676,14.74417

Its been cropped by SketchUp at level 16 then scaled by 0.00254.

How can I figure out where to place the point -9.13722112,14.72997897?

Comment: Just be an artist man

Comment: It should just be `(  (x-x0) * 0.00254,  (y-y0) * 0.00254 )`  where `(x0,y0)` is your origin, and  `(x,y)` is your point of interest?

Comment: Why don't you get ride of the scale (ctrl+a then scale). Once finished, you can set it back if you want.

Comment: I don't understand parts of your description of the problem, such as having (0,0) located at (-9.etc, 14.etc). Why did you choose a scale of .00254? Were you trying to take imperial units into metric? Thats like converting inches to cm and dividing by 1000. How big is the map by default? Is the default size the same as the true size (doubtful from description, even though I would expect terrain data to be 1:1)? If it is not, the scale factor should be on the site you downloaded the file from.

Comment: The scale to 0.00254 is just because otherwise it was to big to work with imo. My issue is exactly that I´m not sure how to find the relative measures. because i know that sketch up grabbed 1 km. so i guess that means from center to edge i cover 1 km. im thinking of something similar to what robin betts said. Only problem is that (0,0) is relative so like if i wanted (-1,0) then its really -9.something,14.something